# Web-app that provides email aliases similar to Yahoo's ones

Tags: web-apps, email, security, spam

**The Current Service**
With Yahoo mail, you they give you a second address like  `foo-*@yahoo.com`.
You can replace the asterisk with whatever string and you can have up to 500 addresses with this template.

The idea is that you don't have to share your actual address and if, say, `foo-bar@yahoo.com` recipient starts to spam you, you simply disable this address.

**Moving from Yahoo**
The problem is that Yahoo seems to move in the direction of asking a phone number to sign in. [This is very dangerous for security](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2019/03/why-phone-numbers-stink-as-identity-proof/) (and imagine when you change your mobile company).
So I am going to move from Yahoo and seeking alternatives, better if without the hassle of paying services.

**Valid Alternatives**
I am looking for antispam aliases and not disposable addresses (which instead are used exactly to spam).
Kindly **avoid** suggesting services where:

- They propose max 10/20 alias (because our digital life require much more sign-ons) and the extras cost a fortune.
- The aliased addresses are temporary (how do you prove your ID after). While Yahoo bills their aliases as disposable, they actually last forever.

It is OK a service forwarding aliases to another email provider.

Comment: Is GMail an acceptable service? [They allow a couple of "undocumented" tricks](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html), although rather than being separate and disable-able aliases, they're filterable.

Comment: Another possible solution is to purchase your own domain, and set it up with an email hosting provider that gives you "full" control over the mail server - that is, allows you to set up forwarders, aliases, or additional accounts "on the fly".